# What is NSEraCalendarUnit?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I was playing around with NSCalendar and NSDateComponents today and I saw constants like NSDayCalendarUnit and NSEraCalendarUnit. NSDayCalendarUnit returns 4 if today is the 4th of December for instance. NSEraCalendarUnit returns the era which is apparently 1 at the time of posting. Anyone care to explain what an era is?

Comment: It's probably AD/BC. Like now it's 2011 AD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Eimantas has it correct.  It's AD/BC (or BCE and C.E. for non-Religious folks).

There's a bit more information about it [in Apple's Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) (linked there).  Look under the "Special Considerations for Historical Dates" section.

And the Date & Time Programming Guide's [Historical Dates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010240-SW1) page has even more information, including on working with eras with backward time flow (i.e. the day which follows December 31, 7 BC is January 1, **6 BC**).

Comment: +1 this is important because (for example) the Japanese calendar uses the Era to denote the reign of a single emperor. So while the Gregorian calendar only had had 2 eras do far, the Japanese calendar has had dozens.